# How to fix that the labels on the triangular will appear?

Tags: diagrams

I have this code:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
S \arrow{r}{\varphi}  \arrow[rd]{\iota} 
  & G \arrow[d,dashleftarrow]{\tilde\varphi} \\
    & F(S)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

The triangular diagram that appears is a one without \tilde\varphi and without \iota as the labels of the arrows.

How do you suggest me to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
S \rar{\varphi}  \drar{\iota}
    & G \dar[dashleftarrow]{\tilde{\varphi}} \\   % maybe "\widetilde" instead of "\tilde"
    & F(S)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]